# Why does MPMoviePlayerController report wrong timestamp after seeking a HTTP Live stream

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

I generate a VOD stream using `mediafilesegmenter`

> ```
> #EXTM3U
> #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
> #EXT-X-VERSION:3
> #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
> #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
> #EXTINF:9.9683,   
> spider0.ts
> ...
> #EXTINF:4.2122,   
> spider473.ts
> #EXT-X-ENDLIST
> ```

I check the timestamp reported by player but it report the wrong timestamp (player shows different video frame comparing with original video) after i seek. I use  player provided by iOS without any customization

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HLS doesn't allows accurate seek due to few features in preparation of video.

Specification - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-05

**First**, the length of the file may differ from the original.
**Second**, the length of the chunks may also differ. That's why there is a difference in the frames in HLS and original file. HLS (Apple's HTTP Live Streaming) use H.264 video - there is no transcoding involved, only a simple dynamic repackaging to convert between formats.

At the same time seek is not working correctly, and only within a chunk, if seek outside chunk we will go to the beginning of a new chunk.
I encounter such a problem on FMS and Wowza and not corrected it.